# Flutter Data Table Row Sums

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-datatable

I am looking for a tabular data widget like DataTable which contains;

- Pagination support
- Sticky header
- Footer row for sums on page

Every page will contain a fixed number of rows if there are enough.
Also, the table will fit screen height but it should be scrollable horizontally because there are dozens of columns.

[image: dummy example]
It will be basically like this dummy presentation.

I started with the catalog widget `PaginatedDataTable` but unfortunately, it has no footer row support and sticky header. Then I thought maybe I could handle it with the Table widget but that widget lacks lots of things.

Then I tried [advanced_table](https://pub.dev/packages/advanced_datatable) and [data_table2](https://pub.dev/packages/data_table_2). Both have sticky headers and pagination support but the footer row became a problem.

I thought that thinking more uncomplicated can make everything better and tried to use ListView but this time even aligning row values with headers became a problem.

Comment: If you’re going the hacky way then I suggest gridview but it might be messy

Comment: Actually I considered it first than I decided that it won't be the best option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this? https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datagrid
its have:

- Stacked headers ,Summary row ,Paging, Loadmore
- etc

[image]

Comment: Actually my path is always crossing with syncfusion package but as I know it was not free. However I checked again with your answer and saw there is a community license. So I will check this package again.

Comment: I am surprised that how this plugin fits all my needs. Thanks for the advice, probably I will spend weeks trying to reinvent the wheel.